# Add my own icon for google map instead of the default google map marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I add new event then it shows the location of that event on the google map and it is showing the google default marker but I have to change the default icon with mine own icon.
I want to add my own icon on the google map instead of the default google marker.how is this possible?

Comment: Read the documentation for Google Maps JS API. Namely https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply.  You can specify any image URL for the marker's `icon` property, e.g. here I'm using an alternative one of Google's, but that could just as easily be a path to an image file on your own server:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
    map: map
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very do able. You can use the Google Api to accomplish this. The maps api is not the easiest thing to use. I find with Google setting up the Api is the hard part. Once you get connected usually they document the code pretty well.

You can do it here, 
[This Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom)

```
// This example uses SVG path notation to add a vector-based symbol
// as the icon for a marker. The resulting icon is a star-shaped symbol
// with a pale yellow fill and a thick yellow border.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922}
  });

  var goldStar = {
    path: 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z',
    fillColor: 'yellow',
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
    scale: 1,
    strokeColor: 'gold',
    strokeWeight: 14
  };

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: goldStar,
    map: map
  });
}
```